Identify short movie about a detective inside a video game
I recall watching this movie about 1/2 hour long in 2008 or 2009. It was downloadable on the internet.
The narrative follows a detective interrogating a man about a criminal who has repeatedly gotten away leaving little trace. The man has a damaged face, and when the detective asks about it, the man acts as though the detective should already know about it. The man gets exasperated with the detective making statements about it all happening again. Eventually, the detective slaps the man. The police catch a break as to the location of the criminal and there is a massive chase scene. They manage to stop the vehicle the criminal is driving only to find that there is nobody inside. The detective is bewildered and then looks at the ground to see the words written:
Level One
Then the movie resets to the beginning. We see the criminal again has his face damaged and the detective asks about it. Now we understand that everyone is in a computer game and the characters are in a time loop replaying the same events over and over again. Only the criminal being questioned seems to realize this.
